# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

hey guys, i am working in a **MVC2** project with **EF4** and i am having the following exception:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

i am trying to do something like this:

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.Amount = response.Amount;
...
_transactionService.Add(transaction);
_transactionService.Save();

OrderPayment orderPayment = new OrderPayment();
orderPayment.AuthorizationTransaction = transaction;
...
_orderPaymentService.AddOrderPayment(orderPayment);
_orderPaymentService.Save();
```

i have 3 layers

1. A repository layer where i have all the **EF4** logic, and the basic CRUD for each entity
2. A service layer that apply all my business logic and uses the repo, of course, i dont have in here any reference to the objectcontext of the **EF4**
3. And the **MVC** stuff in my web layer

the above code belongs to a controller of the web layer, and my repos are:

**OrderPaymentRepo**

```
public void AddOrderPayment(OrderPayment orderPayment)
{
    _pharmacyDpnCtx.OrderPayments.AddObject(orderPayment);
}

public int Save()
{
    return _pharmacyDpnCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

and the **TransactionRepo**:

```
public void Add(Transaction transaction)
{
    _pharmacyDpnCtx.Transactions.AddObject(transaction);
}

public int Save()
{
    return _pharmacyDpnCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

i was researching in the web but a lot of solutions has the **UnityOfWork** to use the same **ObjectContext**, that is the best solution but now i can afford that, any suggestion without **UnityOfWork**

Comment: "Something like"?  Is there more to this code?  Which line shows the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a look at this link - [8 Entity Framework Gotchas](http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=0907071&printmode=true), at the 5th and 6th chapter, there's a full explanation about your question.

Second, the easy thing you can do is to use the same "Context" object in the Save and Add method.